# QScrollBar QPlaintextEdit setValue does not work

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple `QPlainTextEdit`. In `MainWindow` constructor:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("testing");
}
```

And after that I want to scroll:

```
ui->plainTextEdit->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(30);
```

But it does not work. Although if I would create a button and in click-slot run the same code it would have worked:

```
connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]()
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(30); // it works
});
```

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For efficiency reasons, the scrollbars are updated only after displaying the widget, so it must be set a moment after the synchronous task is executed, and for this you can use `QTimer::singleShot()`:

```cpp
QTimer::singleShot(0, [this](){
    ui->plainTextEdit->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(30);
});
```

or `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`:

```cpp
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(ui->plainTextEdit->verticalScrollBar(), "setValue", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(int, 30));
```